# Converting string to DateTime gives wrong result

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a string to `DateTime` object like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/2017","dd/mm/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but I'm getting `DateTime` month number = 1 instead of 12 !!

> Date = {1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: capital `MM` for month. `mm` is minutes

Comment: Custom Date and Time Format Strings   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date format string is using minutes for the month. Use `MM` for month. `mm` is for minutes.

> "mm"  The minute, from 00 through 59.
>   "MM"  The month, from 01 through 12.

Reference: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Which would mean you need to update snippet to...

```
DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/2017","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That's correct. As a reference, here's the [MSDN documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) on .NET custom date and time formats.

Comment: I was just googling to find that exact link to add to the answer